# SSL issue for NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate

I have SSL valid certificate under IIS, but when I open web site via chrome, chrome told me that certificate is not valid NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID.
where could be an issue ?

Comment: what are the certificates `valid not before <date>` and `valid not after <date>`?

Comment: chrome show me  current day as a last day.. but IIS has it upto next year